# NSNotification called twice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using this code to implement `NSNotification` listener :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addUserItemNotification:) name:kFinishFillUserDetails object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

How i remove it:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kFinishFillUserDetails object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

And this is how i call it :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kFinishFillUserDetails object:nil userInfo:dic];
```

And i have this problem:

If i create the viewcontroller and add it to `UINavigationController` and then remove it from the `UINavigationController` and then create another controller from the same type and add it to `UINavigationController`, And then the `NSNotification` called twice and not only once.
Any idea why it happen?

This is how i create the `UIViewController`:

```
UsersViewController *usersVC = [[[UsersViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UsersViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:usersVC animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is deprecated since iOS 6 and it's no called anymore in the view controller life cycle.

Try moving the deregistration code into `dealloc`.

Comment: The problem is that the dealoc is not called too

Comment: Then you'd better show the code you use to remove the VC from the navigation stack.

Comment: [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @MTA if your VC is not deallocated after popping it, it means you have a retain cycle somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriele Petronella has the right of it. viewDidUnload is deprecated. I find the best pattern to use when registering/unregistering NSNotifications is within the viewWillAppear:animated/viewWillDisappear:animated respectively.

Comment: viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear logic is bad design and should be avoided as much as possible, especially in iOS7, where viewWillAppear may be called without DidAppear and so on.